# Laravel not creating objects of specific Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a Model Comment.php and the table comments on the DB.

I have some seeders that are able to insert data in that table and a bunch of other models and controllers already working.

The problem is that whenever im trying to create a new Comment it comes empty. For example:

```
    {
    $comment = new Comment([
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
        'status' => 'active',
        'profile_id' => $request->input('profile_id')
    ]);

    return $comment;
    }
```

returns

```
[]
```

I made sure the Model and the Controller both exists. I can actually index all the comments. I am also using the right Model:

```
use App\Comment;
```

Any idea where should I check or why does Laravel/Eloquent is not recognizing the model when trying to create a new object?

Edit:

This is my Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
public $fillable = ['*'];

public function profile(){
    $this->belongsTo(Profile::class);
}

public function project(){
    $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}

public function scopeOfProject($query,$projectId){
    return $query->where('project_id',$projectId);
}
```

Comment: Don't you get a MassAssignment exception?

Comment: No, I already bypassed that using public $fillable = ['*'];

Comment: Actually I just changed it to

protected $fillable = ['description','status','profile_id','project_id','created_at','updated_at'];

And it is working, I guess ["*"] doesn't work. Muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: Yes it does not, you should use `$guarded` with a non-existant property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public $fillable = ['*'];
```

Was the problem.